# How can I keep a copyright notice on compiled and obfuscated classes?

Tags: android, proguard

I have several apps that in the pre-compiled code have a copyright header on each Java class. After obfuscation and compilation those are removed... even thought I can't mantain them, how should I do to:

- Create a NOTICE file with the copyright to if the code is reverse engineered the notice is still there?
- Add there the copyright or copyleft of the authors that publish code in which the licence obliges the users to it?

Comment: What kind of "comments" do you mean? - Proguard works on compiled Java classes where "normal" in-code comments will have been removed by the compiler long before.

Comment: On the beginning of the file: /** Copyright bla bla bla bla **/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot have comments in a compiled class.

Why do you want to include a copyright notice with your *obfuscated* code?
Why do you want to include a copyright notice in the code of an App?

An apk is not a .jar file which you use to provide library code to other programs. In fact, an apk is meant to be installed on a phone as a standalone application and it is not intended or supposed to have anyone unpack and look into it. (Except for reverse engineering of an App which in most cases is illegal per the software's license agreement and which has few legitimate uses, anyway.)

When you compile java code to a class/dex/whatever the compiler removes the comments. No way to avoid that.

Include the license notice in your assets directory if you're that worried about it.

Comment: That's exactly why. Because you can reverse engineer the APK. And besides, when you are using a code that the license obliges you to mention the author, how are you suppose to do? If you cant have even a notice file?

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN when you compile java code to a class/dex/whatever the compiler removes the comments.  No way to avoid that.  Include the license notice in your assets directory if you're that worried about it.

Comment: If it's on root directory (the same as the manifest) the APK will not contain it?

Comment: You can include any file you like inside the apk with any jar/zip tool. However, I haven't seen a license that would require you to include some notice just in the binary of your software. Usually, you are required to "mention" the original copyright, which, in case of a binary distribution of an exectutable, would include some screen/dialog/Activity that gets shown to the user with the proper notice. - Be sure about what the original license really wants you to do.